# Passing input to optaplanner

Tags: jboss, drools, redhat, optaplanner

I'm using MySql database for Passing input to optaplanner, im creating file similar to nurserostering in optaplanner. How many tables do i need to create if i need to pass the similar data in long01.xml

Am struck on this please do give me some ideas, its my school project.

Also why is this pattern used for

```html
<Pattern ID="0" weight="1">
      <PatternEntries>
        <PatternEntry index="0">
          <ShiftType>L</ShiftType>
          <Day>Any</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
        <PatternEntry index="1">
          <ShiftType>D</ShiftType>
          <Day>Any</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
      </PatternEntries>
    </Pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

The nurse rostering example has 2 XML formats:

- `import` dir XML: defined by the research challenge. Converted to domain objects by the mapping code in the `NurseRosteringImporter`
- `unsolved` dir XML: XStream serialized of the domain objects. So no explicit mapping code needed (beyond the `@XStreamAlias` annotations on the domain classes).

I believe you mention the import dir XML, but the system of the unsolved XML is far more interesting because it has minimal mapping code. `NurseRosteringDAO` reads/writes from unsolved XML. Following the same design, you can also read/write to a database, by using Hibernate-JPA instead of XStream:

[image: integration overview]

Go to hibernate.org to learn Hibernate with JPA annotations. Basically, you'll add some JPA annotations (such as `@Entity` and `@ManyToOne`) on your domain objects and use an `EntityManager(Factory)` to read/write those from the database.